# Comparing dates from table in R, and storing location data using for loop and if statement

Tags: r

Reading data from table tripdata. Trying to store location data for a particular date(2016-01-01) by comparing pickup dates in the table. Keep getting error-missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Import TripData

```
TripData = read.csv("yellow_tripdata_2016-01-01.csv",header=T)
```

Change DateTime format

```
TripData$tpep_pickup_datetime <- as.POSIXlt(TripData$tpep_pickup_datetime,      format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
TripData<-TripData[order(TripData$tpep_pickup_datetime),]
mydate=as.POSIXlt.date("2016-01-01")

 idx = 0
 idx[1:(31*24)] = 1
 idx[(31*24+1)] = nrow(TripData)+1

 #idx[j] is the row index of the first data in hour j
 for(j in 1:(31*24-1)){
  for(i in (idx[j]):nrow(TripData)){
   if(TripData[i,2]== mydate){
    Pickup_longitude = TripData[i,6] #Extract Pickup_longitude from TripData
  Pickup_latitude = TripData[i,7] #Extract Pickup_latitude from TripData
  Pickup = cbind(Pickup_longitude, Pickup_latitude) #Combine longitude and    latitude into a matrix 
    }
    }
   idx[j+1] = i
   mydate = mydate + 3600
    }
```

This is the result for dput(Tripdata)
7.8, 26.76, 18.96, 8.16, 70.01, 6.36, 9.8, 15.3, 12.95, 21.3, 
    8.8, 5.3, 14.16, 9.8, 30.3, 15.8, 27.25, 7.3, 6.96, 5.8, 
    12, 4.8, 11.62, 6.3, 9.3, 29.3, 42.3, 8.3, 17.76, 8.8, 5.3, 
    8.3, 19.3, 13.56, 21.3, 8.3, 17.3, 8.16, 9.3, 21.8, 8.8, 
    7.3, 10.1, 10.56, 12.3, 10.3, 7.55, 8.3, 7.8, 9.8, 12.3, 
    6.3, 7.56, 7.3, 11.75, 3.8, 24.3, 12.36, 30.95, 9.8, 10.56, 
    8.8, 7.3, 18.8, 11.8, 11.15, 9.36, 7.56, 6.96, 12.3, 11.6, 
    10.9, 5.76, 31.56, 11.3, 15.8, 7.56, 3.8, 14.15, 5.3, 13.8, 
    22.56, 9.3, 9.3, 6.3, 9.1, 10.8, 13.39, 10.3, 20.16, 9.36, 
    10.55, 8.8, 10.8, 7.8, 56.3, 16.3, 29.15, 29.16, 21.96, 8.76, 
    12.36, 7.8, 6.8, 5.8, 10.8, 44.81, 7.56, 7.3, 8.3, 22.3, 
    9.12, 12.95, 9.8, 14.76, 7.8, 8.16, 15.36, 43.56, 63.34, 
    6.8, 12.3, 11.8, 6.8, 9.8, 21.19, 6.3, 36.41, 8.16, 7.55, 
    8.8, 11.8, 4.3, 14.16, 10.3, 8.8, 8.3, 17.75, 32.3, 24.3, 
    18.95, 11.16, 8.8, 6.8, 16.62, 8.8, 10.8, 10.3, 11.3, 17.3, 
    6.8, 11.75, 4.8, 65.42, 27.36, 9.3, 54.3, 10.35, 8.3, 26.15, 
    26.75, 33, 9.96, 8.16, 9.3, 6.8, -6.8, 11, 8.15, 5.3, 5.3, 
    9.3, 10.55, 42.35, 17.16, 31.8, 7.55, 6.8, 5.8, 10.3, 17.25, 
    13.55, 13.3, 11.3, 8.75, 40.61, 8.3, 18.3, 37.34, 7.8, 6.8, 
    5.8, 16.3, 6.3, 30.8, 11.8, 10.3, 16.55, 20.75, 8.8, 7.3, 
    58.34, 35.34, 16.55, 14.8, 5.8, 30.96, 7.3, 39.34, 10.8, 
    15.36, 32.3, 12.95, 63.34, 15.8, 8.3, 9.36, 20.38, 8.76, 
    5.3, 6.81, 7.8, 5.8, 29.15, 8.8, 18.95, 9.95, 13.8, 12.25, 
    4.3, 11.76, 10.8, 6.24, 17.8, 23.16, 10.8, 7.55, 50.16, 7.8, 
    12.96, 6.8, 15.96, 29.8, 11.8, 40.8, 29.8, 8.15, 5.8, 10.55, 
    32.3, 19.3, 15.3, 7.56, 7.3, 13.56, 66, 20.8, 11.8, 8.75, 
    8.8, 11.3, 58.34, 8.8, 11.3, 17.16, 22.6, 29.3, 14.15, 17.3, 
    8.3, 10.56, 10.55, 11.3, 8.8, 5.3, 21.3, 12.8, 17.15, 11.3, 
    9.3, 13.78, 13.8, 11.16, 14.3, 5.3, 16.3, 7.55, 8.15, 4.8, 
    6.8, 14.8, 9.3, 8.75, 14.75, 35.76, 5.8, 6.3, 10.8, 11.3, 
    58.34, 22.55, 15.8, 7.3, 9.96, 6.35, 10.3, 6.96, 19.56, 7.55, 
    11.8, 32.25, 7.3, 8.3, 9.96, 13.8, 9.35, 7.3, 8.8, 38.15, 
    4.3, 9.75, 8.3, 7.3, 10.3, 9.13, 17.76, 14.76, 7.8, 15.3, 
    12.8, 13.5, 19.8, 6.3, 9.36, 7.8, 38.3, 19.12, 5.8, 9.8, 
    9.8, 8.3, 10.8, 8.8, 17.3, 20.76, 6.36, 9.3, 11.8, 8.8, 58.34, 
    6.3, 12.8, 15.35, 12.96, 10.14, 35.16, 11.62, 10.3, 38.76, 
    11.3, 27.8, 4.75, 14.75, 17.76, 8.3, 11.16, 9.36, 5.3, 37.84, 
    33.35, 28.3, 47.84, 7.3, 10.56, 18.3, 7.8, 9.3, 18.5, 7.8, 
    42.3, 5.3, 8.8, 5.3, 9.13, 9.12, 6.62, 27.8, 10.8, 37.3, 
    7.3, 8.75, 20.75, 37.01, 13.55, 5.8, 26.16, 6.96, 22.56, 
    6.95, 13.8, 9.36, 6.96, 11.8, 10.56, 10.3, 23.75, 7.8, 9.8, 
    21.35, 11.8, 6.3, 9.75, 53.5, 8.8, 30.36, 6.8, 26.76, 12.36, 
    9.75, 8.16, 11.8, 7.3, 12.36, 10.56, 15.3, 16.56, 11.3, 8.16, 
    28.5, 8.3, 7.56, 16.8, 7.8, 23.8, 9.1, 9.8, 28.56, 7.8, 41.95, 
    30.8, 63.35, 32.8, 32, 15.36, 15.3, 5.3, 20.8, 11.3, 18.3, 
    15.96, 8.3, 15.8, 16.8, 7.8, 7.3, 16.56, 22.8, 6.8, 13.5, 
    52.8, 3.8, 14.3, 5.8, 7.3, 8.3, 35.84, 9.1, 12.3, 24.8, 8.76, 
    5.3, 24.1, 9.95, 6.8, 11.3, 4.8, 14.16, 9.96, 8.3, 6.8, 25.3, 
    24.36, 6.8, 8.76, 23.3, 6.3, 12.36, 24.3, 11.8, 11.8, 5.8, 
    7.25, 6.8, 6.8, 11.15, 9.8, 7.8, 7.8, 11.3, 10.3, 26, 10.8, 
    42.84, 13.8, 7.8, 22.55, 9.8, 8.75, 18.17, 10.8, 20.38, 11.75, 
    21.96, 7.3, 17.3, 18.8, 37.84, 66, 10.3, 6.8, 16.8, 7.3, 
    13.56, 48.8, 5.8, 10.8, 10.3, 10.3, 8.8, 17.76, 11.3, 7.55, 
    14.8, 7.8, 7.3, 4.8, 8.16, 6.5, 14.3, 13.55, 14.15, 17.8, 
    18.59, 8.5, 6.96, 9.8, 12.8, 7.3, 6.8, 11.8, 11.15, 9.35, 
    12.3, 4.8, 8.3, 10, 9.8, 8.16, 14.3, 7.8, 10.8, 20, 12.3, 
    8.3, 10.8, 32.16, 4.8, 69.99, 11.76, 18.36, 11.16, 19.8, 
    3.8, 68.64, 8.3, 19.55, 11.16, 14.04, 38.54, 8.8, 70.01, 
    8.15, 10.35, 6.8, 9.3, 32.84, 12.3, 5.8, 6.8, 51.8, 51.05, 
    14.15, 15.3, 12.96, 7.56, 11.8, 34.84, 60.3, 4.3, 27.35, 
    16.55, 6.8, 11.8, 13.3, 13.3, 17.75, 8.3, 3.8, 9.8, 15.38, 
    11.15, 30.4, 17.16, 46.01, 29.16, 15.3, 5.3, 16.8, 23.3, 
    15.95, 7.8, 9.3, 5.8, 7.8, 12.35, 10.8, 8.3, 27, 25.3, 20.8, 
    21.96, 24.12, 34.61, 11.76, 12.36, 24.35, 8.8, 8.16, 14.69, 
    21.96, 6.93, 7.88, 6.8, 9.8, 10.55, 6.8, 7.88, 10.56, 11, 
    8.5, 9.96, 37.61, 19.3, 9.8, 9, 12.8, 66.84, 8.8, 16.3, 9.8, 
    58.34, 7.8, 6.3, 15.8, 10.8, 12.3, 7.3, 37.56, 63.36, 33.3, 
    8.8, 11.44, 9.3, 9.8, 12.95, 11.15, 8.3, 9.36, 7.56, 17.3, 
    29.8, 8.8, 66.3, 8.8, 8.8, 44.75, 5.3, 9.8, 5.3, 12.8, 9.8, 
    26.8, 12.3, 5.8, 10.3, 7.3, 13.3, 10.3, 11.3, 8.3, 25.8, 
    6.3, 11.16, 11, 37.34, 30.84, 11.15, 10.79, 13.3, 33.3, 19.8, 
    10.3, 8.8, 12.8, 9.8, 14.76, 18.3, 28.3, 63.36, 12.36, 5.3, 
    8.8, 5.6, 8.97, 20.8, 6.8, 5.76, 6.8, 7.56, 27.25, 10.8, 
    17.76, 6.36, 8.75, 8.75, 8.8, 14.69, 13.5, 70.01, 5.8, 9.3, 
    27.96, 26.3, 7.8, 38.21, 27.25, 11.76, 24.36, 8.3, 14.8, 
    7.3, 7.8, 17.3, 8.3, 9.75, 8.15, 6.3, 11.16, 7.55, 5.8, 7.3, 
    9.96, 35.34, 7.3, 11.76, 7.8, 18.36, 20.15, 5.8, 4.8, 13.56, 
    8.8, 68.34, 7.8, 7.8, 13.8, 8.5, 14.3, 7.3, 21.96, 18.8, 
    16.8, 6.3, 33.34, 11.8, 7.56, 6.8, 11, 17.8, 9.35, 13.8, 
    9.3, 27.8, 7.3, 12.96, 9.36, 5.8, 7.85, 11.8, 37.55, 9.12, 
    6.8, 14.76, 7.85, 5.3, 6.3, 7.3, 8.3, 20.8, 18.35, 6.3, 6.8, 
    6.8, 8.3, 30.8, 8.15, 9.96, 10.56, 8.8, 7.8, 14.75, 12.8, 
    50.3, 44.8, 48.35, 22.55, 5.3, 18.8, 15.3, 6.3, 23.16, 15.36, 
    10.3, 13, 42.96, 13.3, 14.8, 10, 13.8, 28.5, 8.75, 10.3, 
    16.56, 23.16, 22.3, 11.3, 10.56, 10.75, 30.95, 9.36, 7.3, 
    7.3, 12.15, 11.3, 7.56, 15.3, 6.8, 10.8, 17.75, 6.96, 7.8, 
    11.16, 7.8, 13.8, 8.3, 14.76, 66, 48.34, 14.3, 15.8, 24.75, 
    37.01, 14.16, 11.8, 14, 9.8, 15.95, 17.8, 5.76, 40.69, 34.3, 
    18.3, 29.84, 8.76, 11.8, 6.8, 13.5, 12.36, 8.16, 13.3, 10.56, 
    11.8, 5.8, 11.3, 26.75, 14.75, 7.3, 10.38, 5.8, 11.3, 21.96, 
    11.16, 70.01, 70.01, 40.34, 9.75, 11.16, 45.38, 12.8, 19.3, 
    106.8, 6.8, 8.8, 19.55, 10.14, 9.3, 9.8, 17.3, 6.36, 6.3, 
    9.3, 4.8, 37.8, 43.48, 6.8, 15.8, 17.8, 15.96, 34.56, 7.3, 
    85.8, 10.35, 7.82, 10.3, 10.8, 6.8, 7.8, 6.3, 8.3, 7.3, 12.35, 
    12.3, 3.8, 14.16, 7.3, 18.3, 11.16, 27.96, 11.3, 32.3, 27.85, 
    7.3, 16.55, 38.84, 7.8, 8.3, 7.56, 11.76, 6.8, 10.3, 48.84, 
    6.3, 35.76, 9.36, 6.8, 7.8, 12.36, 11.3, 31.34, 17.3, 7.85, 
    7.8, 33.34, 10.8, 6.8, 12, 26.3, 61.8, 4.3, 16.3, 9.3, 10.3, 
    7.3, 8.8, 11.8, 7.55, 12.3, 8.3, 63.36, 10.56, 5.16, 9.8, 
    5.8, 19.3, 4.8, 8.8, 10.42, 18.8, 17.25, 7.3, 9.8, 11.15, 
    8.16, 7.8, 24.3, 13.8, 11.8, 17.15, 6.3, 7.8, 6.3, 41.8, 
    17.15, 11.15, 15.95, 7.3, 22.8, 19.8, 10.8, 10.3, 17.3, 8.8, 
    28.55, 13.8, 33, 9.3, 11.3, 7.55, 20.35, 12.36, 12.36, 11.5, 
    11.3, 11.75, 8.19, 9.8, 7.3, 24.3, 7.55, 6.8, 7.56, 11.3, 
    36.35, 7.3, 9.8, 24.3, 17.3, 19.3, 7.3, 9, 8.16, 8.3, 13.39, 
    7.8, 14.12, 15.3, 8.3, 11.76, 15.36, 7.8, 14.76, 6.3, 31.3, 
    7.8, 4.8, 6.8, 25.55, 8.8, 11.8, 5.8, 6.3, 18.35, 8.16, 21.8, 
    44.16, 4.3, 19.8, 20.3, 17.29, 30.8, 8.15, 18.96, 35.16, 
    6.95, 6.8, 22.88, 23.16, 7.8, 19.3, 4.3, 16.3, 6.8, 11.15, 
    8.3, 5.8, 9.3, 8.3, 14.16, 31.55, 9.35, 10.8, 13.3, 13.3, 
    66.34, 10.56, 14.3, 23.76, 6.3, 7.8, 14.16, 9.3, 10.8, 12.36, 
    13.3, 8.8, 8.3, 12.36, 6.3, 10.8, 5.3, 11, 15.36, 15.3, 9.8, 
    8.8, 8.8, 9.3, 17.16, 9.8, 17.8, 7.3, 12.8, 13.8, 55.61, 
    11, 23, 46.34, 6.8, 6.3, 17.75, 34.3, 6.8, 8.8, 15.3, 13.56, 
    7.8, 10.38, 9.8, 11.15, 12.36, 15.8, 20.3, 6.36, 14.75, 26.8, 
    12.8, 42.99, 17.8, 7.8, 14.3, 12.8, 8.3, 11.3, 9.36, 13.3, 
    11.8, 10.35, 5.3, 30.3, 8.3, 8.3, 7.3, 23, 9.12, 8.3, 13.8, 
    25.3, 9.12, 9.35, 6.95, 8.76, 14.16, 13.8, 6.3, 7.3, 5.8, 
    41.8, 16.8, 19.8, 21.3, 8.3, 8.75, 15.8, 7.3, 6.3, 11.16, 
    25.3, 7.8, 6.36, 4.3, 7.25, 12.55, 8.3, 7.8, 10.55, 11.75, 
    21.8, 38.8, 8.8, 11.76, 9.49, 7.8, 12.95, 7.3, 7.8, 11.76, 
    9.8, 27.36, 6.8, 12.8, 12.3, 7.56, 10.8, 8.8, 8.76, 8.16, 
    44.8, 10.56, 10.38, 6.3, 8.3, 12.8, 5.8, 11.8, 15.8, 6.3, 
    8.8, 5.8, 8.16, 5.8, 15.3, 8.3, 16.55, 10.3, 13.39, 42.41, 
    19.55, 58.61, 16.8, 18.17, 8.3, 6.8, 36.84, 36.3, 5.3, 11.76, 
    12.36, 8.3, 17.16, 13.8, 58.34, 10.8, 12.3, 6.3, 23.3, 16.56, 
    7.3, 54.96, 10, 10.3, 9.75, 6.3, 11.75, 8.75, 8.8, 5.8, 28.55, 
    6.3, 7.8, 7.8, 8.3, 8.8, 12.8, 7.3, 7.3, 14.3, 5.8, 8.8, 
    8.16, 6.8, 26.68, 6.3, 8.75, 16.8, 39.3, 9.13, 9.45, 11.75, 
    10.3, 10.35, 12.8, 11.8, 6.8, 6.8, 11.3, 20, 8.75, 12.3, 
    17.8, 12.3, 14.3, 4.3, 10.8, 7.55, 6.3, 7.8, 6.8, 23.76, 
    5.8, 17.76, 5.8, 7.3, 8.8, 27.88, 9.36, 6.3, 7.56, 18.3, 
    8.16, 8.3, 21.8, 8.3, 5.8, 38.55, 8.19, 8.3, 8.8, 11.8, 10.8, 
    10.8, 12.85, 8.15, 68.34, 19.3, 7.3, 7.56, 4.8, 6.3, 9.96, 
    13.8, 8.75, 9.96, 9.36, 20.16, 20.8, 8.75, 26.8, 7.55, 9.8, 
    7.8, 9, 8.16, 21.19, 5.8, 6.3, 5.8, 18, 10.8, 11.3, 5.3, 
    34.3, 17.3, 8.76, 9.5, 12.96, 26.3, 15.95, 12.36, 6.36, 7.8, 
    54.3, 11.3, 20, 25.55, 12.96, 17.76, 16.64, 20.55, 8.16, 
    9.36, 7.8, 6.8, 12.3, 7.55, 13.5, 7.8, 11.8, 13.3, 22.3, 
    10.3, 32.19, 10.56, 7.3, 7.8, 9.3, 12.3, 10.8, 9.95, 7.8, 
    7.3, 7.3, 7.3, 18.96, 11.76, 11.16, 11.15, 11, 22.56, 10.8, 
    46.92, 8.3, 8.8, 5.8, 6, 11.3, 6.3, 20.38, 41.76, 12.8, 11.75, 
    11.3, 13.56, 43.61, 44.16, 4.3, 22.3, 13.8, 14.3, 25.3, 6.8, 
    6.3, 17.29, 5.8, 9.35, 25.3, 11.76, 12.96, 27.8, 11.8, 12.8, 
    72.89, 12.36, 8.76, 7.8, 8.3, 42.8, 9.96, 26.3, 9.3, 8.8, 
    9.3, 14.16, 6.3, 9.96, 58.34, 6.3, 10.56, 7.8, 14.3, 8.8, 
    6.8, 16.3, 24.35, 5.3, 8.5, 5.3, 11.3, 34.34, 8.5, 13.3, 
    7.8, 8.3, 15, 11.83, 52.8, 5.3, 10.8, 6.3, 13.8, 38.75, 6.62, 
    17.29, 17.75, 13.3, 8.16, 31.3, 21.3, 9.35, 5.8, 10.8, 10.8, 
    6.3, 8.3, 13.8, 14.3, 6.3, 9.35, 7.3, 25.8, 12.8, 13.3, 36.96, 
    6.36, 6.6, 15.8, 10.8, 10.3, 15.35, 10.05, 12.96, 6.96, 35.76, 
    7.8, 12.96, 7.3, 9.8, 20.75, 7.25, 14.3, 40.55, 14.69, 21.8, 
    14.3, 11.3, 9, 11.8, 22.56, 38.34, 28.56, 56, 7.8, 29.16, 
    10.55, 10.56, 11.27, 7.25, 42.29, 5.8, 13.35, 10.3, 7.8, 
    11.3, 51.34, 15.8, 11.15, 5.8, 19.3, 10, 13.56, 8.3, 10.8, 
    7.3, 11.75, 8.3, 12.36, 26.3, 8.8, 16, 13.8, 27.25, 10.8, 
    12.35, 7.8, 25.3, 7.3, 11.62, 52.8, 8.16, 14.04, 23.16, 7.8, 
    7.8, 11.76, 15.96, 12.3, 5.8, 5.3, 13.55, 5.76, 17.16, 8.75, 
    12.3, 9.36, 3.8, 5.16, 15.3, 14.8, 6.8, 15.36, 21.95, 7.8, 
    42.89, 70.84, 16.8, 10.38, 29.3, 11.76, 6.36, 10.8, 11.75, 
    8.8, 6.96, 12.35, 19.8, 6.35, 7.25, 17.76, 6.3, 9.3, 8.75, 
    11.76, 9.35, 19.2, 6.8, 15.99, 11.15, 12.36, 9.96, 7.8, 11.15, 
    63.35, 5.3, 11.3, 9.3, 47.15, 13.3, 17.76, 37, 9.8, 18.5, 
    9.96, 18, 18.3, 23.16, 8.8, 11.76, 14.8, 17.16, 8.8, 6.3, 
    14.16, 27.3, 8.8, 6.3, 19.8, 6.8, 10.55, 12.74, 11.75, 9.8, 
    44.3, 7.8, 12.3, 7.8, 13.8, 8.75, 40.3, 7.3, 12.8, 4.56, 
    5.3, 10.8, 16.8, 15.8, 12.8, 9.3, 9.3, 9.5, 55.8, 8.76, 24.96, 
    5.8, 26.8, 7.54, 10.38, 10.79, 15.3, 40.34, 20.3, 18.8, 7.3, 
    12.3, 34.8, 8.8, 11.84, 17.25, 5.8, 18.3, 11.3, 16.3, 30.03, 
    10.58, 9.3, 12.3, 52.8, 8.3, 8.3, 8.15, 6.67, 11.76, 29.76, 
    8.8, 9.8, 23.15, 6.3, 18.3, 9.36, 7.3, 29.6, 11.75, 7.8, 
    10.8, 9.75, 6.3, 11.75, 6.3, 6.35, 10.8, 9.95, 9.3, 6.8, 
    6.3, 6.8, 7.8, 9.8, 11.15, 26.39, 5.3, 6.3, 4.8, 10.8, 7.3, 
    10.56, 15.8, 17.16, 13.8, 17.25, 8.16, 9.96, 16.8, 24.35, 
    21.3, 14.76, 9.3, 6.96, 18.95, 12.8, 18.3, 7.56, 11.76, 52.8, 
    9, 9.3, 14.8, 5.8, 6.8, 11.44, 15.36, 9.8, 15.8, 25.74, 18.8, 
    14.3, 9.8, 15.8, 19.55, 7.8, 8.3, 8.3, 24.3, 21, 13.55, 10.7, 
    34.56, 9.36, 22.88, 23.16, 5.55, 6.36, 12.25, 12.8, 12.8, 
    5.3, 8.3, 5.8, 10.56, 10.3, 19.75, 8.8, 8.76, 19.3, 14.16, 
    32.3, 10.8, 17.15, 8.76, 8.3, 20.3, 5.8, 12.8, 17.8, 18.36, 
    6.96, 10.3, 8.3, 18.35, 19.3, 8.76, 45.8, 10.3, 7.3, 9.36, 
    7.3, 12.3, 11.75, 25.8, 9.3, 6.36, 16.62, 7.55, 32.8, 11.3, 
    12.96, 9.3, 6.3, 7.3, 36.34, 15.8, 10.3, 36.96, 14.8, 8.8, 
    17.8, 9.3, 12.96, 12.8, 8.3, 7.56, 30.3, 18.8, 8.8, 4.3, 
    9.36, 17.85, 7.3, 118.84, 15.3, 18.3, 6.95, 8.8, 8.8, 6.3, 
    8.8, 16.3, 26.8, 9.3, 8.8, 11.76, 23.79, 17.8, 35.84, 34.3, 
    6.36, 8.8, 10.56, 8.3, 7.3, 18.96, 8.8, 15.36, 5.3, 12.6, 
    12.3, 10.3, 34.8, 43.3, 12.3, 5.8, 11, 11, 52.8, 10.8, 55.3, 
    16.8, 14.3, 19.8, 54.8, 10.14, 13.3, 12.3, 14.3, 11.3, 9.8, 
    5.3, 7.8, 10.56, 7.8, 26.16, 8.3, 16.56, 13.3, 10.8, 9.3, 
    7.3, 15.96, 6.3, 22.8, 9.95, 7.3, 8.75, 13.3, 11, 7.52, 10.3, 
    13.56, 11.3, 4.8, 17.15, 10.8, 9.95, 11.62, 6.8, 15.38, 12.8, 
    11.8, 8.8, 9.3, 12.35, 75.84, 23.14, 13.8, 9.96, 31.56, 11.3, 
    24.8, 16.3, 6.96, 18.3, 18.8, 9.3, 9.3, 30.34, 9.96, 11.3, 
    9.99, 11.8, 68.16, 12.36, 8.3, 17.25, 16.64, 5.8, 17.8, 21.6, 
    6.8, 5.8, 7.25, 9.8, 4.3, 9.96, 5.3, 13.57, 17.8, 10.8, 8.3, 
    6.8, 20.16, 14.3, 4.3, 7.8, 7.3, 8.3, 8.8, 6.8, 21.3, 67.34, 
    19.3, 60.3, 11, 7.25, 9.8, 14.8, 53.04, 24.36, 40.34, 7.56, 
    11.76, 15.3, 8.75, 13.8, 17.16, 25.8, 5.8, 5.75, 8.8, 31.8, 
    6.96, 12.35, 17.8, 23.14, 9.49, 6.8, 7.56, 7.8, 12.95, 8.15, 
    9.95, 10.56, 7.8, 16.3, 23.8, 5.3, 9.3, 12.36, 46.62, 8.15, 
    20.16, 8.3, 12.8, 19.3, 9.3, 17.25, 9.8, 14.16, 7.8, 14.15, 
    42.92, 6.96, 11.8, 39.36, 35.16, 20.75, 8.8, 10.56, 4.8, 
    9.3, 6.3, 10, 16.3, 46.61, 6.8, 7.8, 15.3, 16.3, 18.3, 12.3, 
    12.96, 10.8, 6.3, 7.8, 11.76, 12.36, 12.8, 6.8, 5.3, 9.8, 
    34.8, 22.25, 16.3, 28.56, 20.75, 12.36, 13.3, 13.3, 29.8, 
    6.6, 12.25, 38.34, 38.21, 7.8, 33.3, 8.3, 8.8, 9.35, 7.3, 
    10, 8.15, 5.8, 43.3, 9.8, 7.3, 7.88, 15.8, 9.3, 44.15, 8.3, 
    14.15, 7.3, 4.8, 10.56, 11.76, 5.8, 46.01, 33.3, 9.3, 15.3, 
    24.3, 39.41, 14.3, 17.76, 14.75, 5.8, 4.8, 44.12, 10.3, 5.8, 
    25.7, 6.8, 24, 15.36, 8.5, 14.8, 25.8, 17.8, 8.8, 11.3, 24.36, 
    22.05, 33.36, 10.35, 13.3, 24.75, 32.34, 13.3, 9.75, 25.74, 
    6.8, 7.8, 15.36, 14.16, 9.8, 15.8, 11.8, 31.84, 9.3, 8.84, 
    17.76, 12.8, 30.8, 6.85, 5.8, 8.8, 7.8, 7.8, 9.8, 9.8, 6.96, 
    9.8, 7.56, 14.3, 10.3, 6.3, 7.8, 17.75, 6.96, 42.84, 8.8, 
    6.96, 9.96, 29.76, 6.8, 14.8, 15.36, 8.8, 8.76, 8.3, 15.8, 
    8.8, 11.8, 11.3, 16.56, 20.3, 14.16, 6.3, 54.3, 6.36, 8.74, 
    20.75, 7.3, 6.36, 61.34, 6.36, 13.8, 23.3, 15.8, 7.3, 16.56, 
    8.3, 35.34, 12.95, 7.3, 18.8, 12.3, 20.15, 11.15, 9.49, 8.8, 
    11.16, 37.34, 11.15, 8.3, 58.3, 14.1, 41.19, 6.8, 16.8, 18.95, 
    15, 45.8, 19.3, 9.8, 14.15, 8.8, 6.89, 18.3, 5.8, 34.55, 
    21.62, 14.75, 19.3, 26.76, 24.3, 16.8, 10.56, 13.8, 22.3, 
    38.21, 9.8, 13.5, 7.3, 10.56, 60.34, 12.8, 3.8, 36.35, 9.8, 
    12.3, 12.36, 36.3, 29.34, 18.96, 26.76, 6.8, 6.3, 14.76, 
    26.3, 6.67, 14.76, 70.01, 6.3, 66, 16.55, 6.3, 12.8, 17.8, 
    6.36, 18.36, 8.3, 12.36, 37.01, 12.8, 14.8, 8.5, 20.75, 8.76, 
    22.55, 21.3, 11.3, 4.3, 6.3, 7.3, 5.8, 5.3, 8.8, 19.12, 9.35, 
    25.8, 34.56, 24.3, 9.8, 8.8, 13.8, 10.8, 17.3, 20.3, 13, 
    10.38, 7.9, 14.8, 11.16, 40.8, 16.3, 11.75, 7.25, 8.3, 10.55, 
    6.3, 14.75, 17.25, 9.36, 6.3, 11.3, 7.8, 10.3, 15.36, 9.75, 
    7.8, 62.8, 9.8, 8.75, 7.56, 10.3, 10.8, 6.96, 19.56, 6.96, 
    6.8, 8.84, 9.8, 11.3, 11.3, 8.76, 11.8, 11.4, 13.3, 14.8, 
    12.8, 29.3, 22.3, 9.3, 9.8, 38.8, 11.16, 41.05, 53.15, 7.3, 
    4.8, 8.8, 10.8, 19.8, 9.1, 17.8, 17.15, 16.3, 8.8, 16.3, 
    13.35, 21.19, 10.8, 16.3, 7.3, 36, 13.55, 11.3, 8.8, 17.15, 
    68.15, 13.3, 27.25, 8.84, 45.39, 9.36, 8.76, 7.8, 7.3, 38.19, 
    18.95, 12.36, 58.34, 5.8, 12.3, 12.3, 11.15, 26.16, 7.8, 
    13.8, 69.99, 12.35, 5.3, 8.3, 13.56, 7.54, 9.3, 11.76, 5.8, 
    6.96, 9.3, 7.3, 15.96, 9.75, 8.76, 7.8, 7.3, 12.3, 8.16, 
    9.8, 5.8, 15.35, 11.3, 46.01, 11.8, 6.96, 41.21, 7.3, 16.8, 
    28.8, 12.25, 9.3, 8.3, 6.8, 26.16, 4.8, 15.8, 7.3, 14.75, 
    7.8, 9.75, 6.8, 8.4, 11.15, 8.8, 21.95, 15.8, 5.8, 6.3, 11.3, 
    8.8, 6.36, 28.01, 11.75, 7.3, 11.3, 6.3, 10.3, 65.34, 34.56, 
    7.8, 10.56, 29.16, 34.55, 12.05, 9.96, 7.3, 6.8, 7.3, 12.3, 
    12.8, 15.8, 58.34, 6.3, 6.8, 12.8, 8.16, 38.55, 54.99, 12.25, 
    8.8, 15.8, 5.8, 6.96, 16.56, 4.3, 11.76, 7.8, 6.96, 9.3, 
    17.3, 9.3, 25.3, 11.76, 9.3, 11.76, 7.55, 8.8, 17.8, 44.19, 
    24.3, 7.8, 14.12, 6.96, 8.3, 9.35, 7.56, 17.3, 37.56, 34.01, 
    9.49, 8.8, 14.75, 12, 21.35, 10.75, 8.15, 14.16, 14.8, 23.16, 
    10.3, 12.8, 9.3, 5.8, 6.96, 12.36, 11.76, 9.3, 6.96, 16.3, 
    5.3, 21.3, 7.3, 17.8, 13.8, 6.96, 13.3, 14.8, 7.3, 5.8, 10.56, 
    20.8, 9.3, 23.3, 11.3, 17.8, 20.3, 6.96, 4.8, 6.3, 17.16, 
    29.3, 8.3, 7.56, 11.3, 9.36, 7.8, 13, 23.3, 9.49, 15.36, 
    6.96, 10.8, 6.8, 8.16, 12.8, 17.25, 10.3, 14.1, 10.8, 6.8, 
    8.97, 8.3, 11.3, 11.8, 7.8, 26.15, 11.75, 8.3, 6.8, 33.36, 
    20.75, 7.8, 31.56, 14.16, 8.8, 9.8, 10.8, 8.8, 10.8, 7.3, 
    12.85, 16.3, 16, 7.8, 9.3, 9.3, 16.55, 9.3, 12.8, 12.35, 
    7.8, 8.3, 58.34, 11.3, 7.8, 25.8, 8.8, 9.3, 8.3, 14.8, 25.3, 
    7.3, 11, 13.56, 12.36, 9.3, 19.55, 8.8, 11.8, 10.8, 9.3, 
    11.62, 9.36, 9.68, 7.3, 11.3, 12.3, 6.8, 11.3, 27.8, 10.56, 
    7.8, 26.75, 5.8, 7.8, 9.8, 7.8, 8.3, 6.8, 11.62, 13.8, 17.16, 
    12.3, 7.8, 12.35, 12.35, 11.16, 30.96, 6.3, 13.3, 11.8, 11.16, 
    10.14, 9.35, 7.8, 6.96, 23.3, 10.56, 6.3, 70.01, 10.3, 16.3, 
    6.8, 19.8, 11.76, 25.8, 6.3, 12.36, 8.3, 26.8, 7.8, 7.8, 
    9.5, 32.3, 23.1, 18.95, 12.3, 11.3, 8.76, 20.16, 6.8, 8.16, 
    8.8, 17.8, 69.99, 7.3, 11.76, 9.8, 54.99, 11.75, 10.55, 12.96, 
    9.8, 12.3, 9.8, 72.88, 21.19, 27.3, 13.3, 4.3, 12.36, 11, 
    9.3, 27.8, 8.3, 30.84, 3.8, 40.3, 7.3, 11.8, 9.3, 7.8, 7.3, 
    6.3, 48.3, 14.3, 19.3, 65.76, 6.8, 13.8, 18.96, 17.8, 5.8, 
    8.3, 5.3, 5.8, 44.81, 16.3, 8.16, 8.3, 9.8, 9.8, 8.8, 9.3, 
    11.76, 6.8, 11.3, 10.3, 27.95, 8.8, 15.8, 17.8, 6.3, 23.8, 
    47.8, 13.8, 20.16, 70.01, 47.16, 7.8, 20.16, 8.3, 6.95, 34.3, 
    9.95, 20.8, 11.3, 37.3, 6.35, 14.75, 14.3, 7.3, 7.56, 10.3, 
    5.3, 25.55, 14.69, 45.8, 16.3, 35.21, 9.36, 53.8, 8.3, 40.55, 
    34.34, 8.19, 4.8, 12.8, 11, 9.96, 7.87, 11.16, 36.8, 9.95, 
    7.3, 15.34, 9.36, 9.3, 9.8, 9.95, 22.56, 10.8, 13.8, 47, 
    11.3, 6.8, 9.8, 11.76, 24.35, 16.3, 11.76, 14.76, 4.8, 9.3, 
    11.3, 24.3, 12.3, 19.3, 7.8, 5.3, 12.3, 9.8, 6.96, 13.3, 
    9.35, 21.35, 8.8, 7.3, 13.56, 8.3, 41.04, 8.15, 5.76, 6.3, 
    25.3, 11.62, 8.19, 10.3, 24.8, 4.3, 17.15, 14.8, 6.8, 12.3, 
    17.3, 7.3, 21.8, 9.36, 18.3, 9.3, 11.84, 42.92, 11.75, 22.3, 
    21.3, 14.8, 6.95, 11.3, 22.82, 9.8, 24.35, 5.3, 8.3, 11.8, 
    16.62, 6.3, 5.8, 15.3, 30.36, 12.3, 13.3, 18.96, 9.49, 13.3, 
    11.8, 8.76, 9.3, 16.8, 6.8, 6.8, 20.76, 19.8, 18.36, 21.36, 
    6.8, 6.8, 8.8, 7.85, 7.8, 11.3, 9.3, 9.95, 12.95, 8.16, 7.54, 
    9.35, 22.56, 26.75, 16.6, 10.3, 12.96, 6.8, 17.15, 7.8, 10.56, 
    7.8, 6.3, 6.35, 6.8, 7.56, 43.3, 6.8, 12.35, 15.36, 65.38, 
    7.3, 13.8, 15.8, 7.3, 19.8, 13.3, 11.3, 14.15, 70.01, 5.8, 
    10.55, 39.75, 12.3, 9.3, 8.75, 5.8, 17.25, 5.8, 6.8, 35.16, 
    16.3, 17.8, 21.8, 22.56, 16.3, 10.3, 8.3, 8.3, 10.14, 18, 
    9.3, 12.8, 9, 6.36, 7.8, 11.76, 49.8, 24.95, 8.15, 8.3, 9.8, 
    8.8, 14.16, 42.35, 5.3, 70.01, 21.36, 7.8, 10, 20.8, 21, 
    7.3, 36.3, 8.3, 11.3, 66.3, 24.8, 8.8, 4.8, 6.36, 12.36, 
    15.8, 12.8, 17.88, 4.8, -4.8, 14.3, 8.15, 6.8, 32.8, 40.8, 
    11.62, 6.36, 9.36, 13.3, 13.55, 17.8, 8.5, 8.16, 15.8, 7.3, 
    6.8, 11.16, 66, 7.8, 8.3, 14.8, 7.3, 12.25, 27.36, 4.8, 15.8, 
    25.3, 21.3, 11.3, 8.3, 15.36, 41.3, 9.95, 10.56, 10.56, 8.8, 
    16.8, 7.8, 6.3, 20.8, 11.8, 8.8, 11.8, 13.8, 4.3, 8.75, 12.8, 
    18.8, 7.3, 8.8, 6.95, 8.75, 6.8, 38.16, 13.5, 10.3, 16.55, 
    32.76, 33.54, 27.96, 7.85, 10.8, 7.3, 8.3, 7.3, 10.56, 12.36, 
    12.8, 16.56, 11.6, 23.76, 5.76, 13.55, 6.8, 7.8, 58.34, 10.3, 
    8.8, 12.96, 10.3, 8.3, 7.3, 15.3, 13.5, 9.3, 20.76, 7.3, 
    10.3, 3.8, 10.14, 35.34, 26.15, 13.56, 14.72, 70.01, 10.05, 
    7.3, 13.3, 18.8, 10.56, 7.3, 5.3, 8.8, 37.3, 10.3, 6.3, 9.75, 
    16.8, 6.8, 29.8, 9.3, 14.76, 52.8, 22.25, 8.8, 6.8, 21.3, 
    19.3, 41.3, 7.25, 5.8, 12.8, 9.8, 16.3, 24.4, 10.56, 29.75, 
    7.55, 10.8, 18.96, 5.3, 8.3, 6.35, 8.75, 9.3, 13.3, 8.8, 
    9.3, 35.8, 10.8, 9.3, 10.14, 9.3, 17.76, 11.16, 14.8, 7.8, 
    8.3, 10.8, 12.88, 8.3, 12.3, 7.3, 10.3, 30.95, 6.3, 30.96, 
    4.8, 10.14, 14.8, 22.49, 18.8, 13.3, 21.3, 7.55, 11.3, 5.3, 
    13.5, 10.8, 9.35, 58.34, 19.75, 8.16, 20.16, 11.16, 15.36, 
    11.15, 9.96, 16.3, 17.3, 34.84, 7.55, 8.84, 7.8, 11.3, 32.3, 
    16.56, 35.84, 11.62, 6.3, 4.3, 13.3, 8.3, 8.3, 19.8, 5.8, 
    8.3, 6.3, 11.56, 7.8, 9.36, 23.3, 5.3, 6.3, 8.8, 15.8, 5.8, 
    13.3, 6.8, 16.56, 23.8, 6.3, 7.3, 35.15, 14.16, 6.8, 8.16, 
    9.8, 14.3, 18.95, 6.3, 15.96, 7.56, 11.16, 12.36, 7.56, 8.8, 
    12.88, 19.56, 14.16, 44.19, 6.8, 7.8, 8.75, 5.8, 8.8, 9.41, 
    40.6, 7.8, 5.8, 20.3, 17.16, 21.8, 6.96, 17.3, 45.36, 8.16, 
    5.8, 8.15, 9.45, 23.16, 52.8, 9.3, 24.12, 6.8, 6.93, 13.8, 
    8.75, 7.56, 12.8, 26.16, 7.8, 8.5, 36.41, 13.3, 8.76, 7.3, 
    6.8, 9.8, 6.8, 46.84, 17.29, 19.3, 36.39, 51.36, 21.36, 8.3, 
    13.3, 12.8, 9.96, 64.34, 8.8, 10.14, 17.25, 6.35, 6.35, 8.8, 
    6.96, 9.95, 60.95, 7.3, 8.3, 16.55, 8.15, 18.3, 7.8, 7.8, 
    6.96, 9.3, 12.8, 10.3, 9.3, 17.3, 6.8, 40.3, 6.8, 28.8, 25.55, 
    8.76, 5.3, 19.8, 9.95, 4.3, 20.38, 39.8, 7.55, 6.8, 13.3, 
    14.8, 12.8, 23.5, 13.55, 12.74, 4.3, 11.3, 7.56, 19.8, 9.8, 
    7.56, 6.8, 25.8, 11.8, 22.55, 17.3, 9.12, 70.01, 5.3, 10.8, 
    63.34, 4.8, 9.8, 14.75, 4.3, 6.3, 9.3, 16.64, 15, 8.8, 12.3, 
    10.3, 28.95, 58.34, 21.8, 20.3, 39.35, 10.8, 46.8, 11.6, 
    7.8, 10.55, 5.3, 18.8, 11.05, 19.3, 6.8, 17.3, 6.3, 9.8, 
    6.8, 6.3, 16.8, 9.36, 16.3, 18.3, 9.95, 13.3, 8.8, 23.8, 
    5.8, 6.8, 7.56, 11.8, 20.75, 14.16, 18.95, 23.76, 6.96, 14.8, 
    7.3, 71.76, 8.3, 6.8, 7.8, 9.3, 14.16, 9.96, 9.35, 9.3, 9.35, 
    10.8, 17.3, 16, 13.3, 12.8, 13.3, 19.56, 13.8, 5.8, 8.3, 
    16.55, 8.75, 46.8, 15.8, 10.38, 9.36, 11.75, 5.8, 40.8, 11.15, 
    70.01, 12.3, 25.3, 5.3, 35.3, 13.3, 15.36, 10.3, 8.3, 10.8, 
    7.3, 9.8, 7.3, 12.7, 16.56, 11.8, 5.8, 5.76, 26.15, 17.16, 
    5.8, 6.95, 14.8, 17, 15.96, 9.96, 9.96, 6.96, 6.85, 13.56, 
    12.3, 22.8, 6.3, 16.3, 14.16, 6.3, 8.16, 9.35, 11.3, 15.96, 
    6.3, 41.16, 7.56, 46.3, 26.34, 11.16, 12.3, 11.76, 12.95, 
    6.8, 13.56, 7.25, 8.8, 6.96, 12.88, 18.96, 8.16, 7.3, 11, 
    9.3, 19.24, 27.8, 9.8, 27.3, 18.36, 15.3, 10.8, 14, 6.96, 
    32.3, 8.16, 10.3, 12.8, 22.8, 13.8, 11.3, 10.8, 7.8, 9.96, 
    5.8, 9.8, 8.8, 8.3, 17.8, 7.3, 32.76, 16, 8.8, 8.76, 11.76, 
    12.8, 14.75, 13.55, 58.34, 63.36, 7.3, 11.3, 10.56, 7.3, 
    63.35, 37.56, 12.36, 7.3, 15.35, 13, 24.3, 11.3, 10.8, 5.75, 
    11.16, 9.8, 20.3, 5.3, 14.3, 15.18, 15.8, 8.75, 9.96, 9.8, 
    12.96, 14.3, 6.95, 6.3, 15.8, 6.3, 10.8, 6.3, 23.76, 8.75, 
    8.3, 8.3, 37.55, 15.3, 17.8, 24.36, 26.3, 7.8, 12.3, 8.3, 
    29.8, 9.96, 5.8, 39.36, 21.36, 32.3, 7.56, 9.35, 44.84, 21.8, 
    9.8, 14.3, 9.3, 10.8, 10.79, 25.38, 10.3, 7.87, 11.76, 15.96, 
    16.56, 8.3, 13.3, 13.3, 9.3, 8.8, 18.33, 15.3, 9.3, 11.6, 
    21.3, 19.12, 5.76, 3.8, 9.35, 13.3, 7.3, 64.3, 12.35, 19.12, 
    8.3, 20.76, 42.69, 9.3, 47.3, 14.16, 6.3, 8.3, 5.3, 10.8, 
    18.3, 8.8, 6.96, 9.3, 7.56, 19.8, 8.8, 7.8, 38.16, 8.3, 13.3, 
    6.8, 8.8, 19.89, 32.81, 47.25, 10.8, 7.3, 8.16, 6.8, 7.8, 
    6.8, 51.14, 16, 7.8, 7.8, 13.56, 14.76, 6.3, 8.15, 14.04, 
    14.75, 9.8, 6.8, 5.3, 9.35, 15.36, 8.5, 57.8, 9.3, 10.8, 
    17.19, 9.3, 12.85, 15.96, 18.3, 15.36, 15.96, 17.25, 15.8, 
    9.35, 6.36, 11.3, 8.16, 9.8, 18.35, 10.3, 18.3, 8.8, 12.35, 
    8.75, 7.3, 68.34, 15.8, 17.3, 11.76, 9.36, 10.3, 19.8, 7.25, 
    8.8, 9.96, 50.8, 5.3, 10.3, 17, 8.8, 5.76, 8.16, 9.8, 11.3, 
    69.99, 23.16, 8.75, 7.85, 7.8, 37.55, 21.36, 63.36, 21.8, 
    23.5, 70.01, 17.25, 10.8, 8.8, 11.8, 5.8, 6.96, 6.8, 19.75, 
    8.5, 6.3, 9.8, 11.3, 14.8, 8.5, 41.3, 5.3, 46, 29.8, 8.3, 
    33.8, 11.16, 7.3, 12.3, 63.36, 15.3, 15.95, 9.8, 7.8, 11.8, 
    10.3, 20.16, 6.8, 15.96, 14.75, 16.8, 6.8, 16.3, 6.3, 14.8, 
    20.8, 33.3, 17.76, 8.8, 14.3, 25, 22.8, 26.75, 17.8, 11.76, 
    11.8, 10.56, 14.16, 12.36, 9.35, 5.8, 6.3, 15.96, 19.3, 16.56, 
    17.76, 26.39, 9.8, 17.25, 12.8, 6.3, 16.64, 10.3, 70.01, 
    7.8, 6.8, 11.16, 13.8, 17.3, 13.3, 8.3, 9.96, 20.8, 63.34, 
    7.8, 9.3, 14.15, 6.36, 10.8, 39.3, 27.88, 10.3, 10.8, 6.8, 
    11.15, 49.01, 12.09, 33.3, 14.3, 12.36, 22.55, 16.64, 21.96, 
    5.8, 18.5, 12.88, 53.76, 9.36, 6.3, 34.34, 13.3, 6.8, 16.55, 
    20.3, 10.56, 9.96, 4.3, 7.3, 23.8, 11.3, 17.16, 13.8, 9.3, 
    17.16, 15.38)), .Names = c("VendorID", "tpep_pickup_datetime", 
"tpep_dropoff_datetime", "passenger_count", "trip_distance", 
"pickup_longitude", "pickup_latitude", "RatecodeID", "store_and_fwd_flag", 
"dropoff_longitude", "dropoff_latitude", "payment_type", "fare_amount", 
"extra", "mta_tax", "tip_amount", "tolls_amount", "improvement_surcharge", 
"total_amount"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -345036L
))

> 

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: it looks like it didin't print the full thing because it was too many rows. you should try doing something like `dput(TripData[1:50,]`, just ensure there is at least 1 occurrence of 01-01-2016 in the rows that you choose. (i.e. if the first occurrence is row 112 do `dput(TripData[100:150,]`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you just use filtering

here is a solution in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- TripData %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::date(tpep_pickup_datetime) %>%
  filter(date == mydate) %>%
  select(pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude)
```

here is one using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
td <- as.data.table(TripData)
td$tpep_pickup_datetime <- as.POSIXct(td$tpep_pickup_datetime)
mydate <- as.POSIXct(mydate)

td1 <- td[, date := lubridate::date(tpep_pickup_datetime)
          ][date == mydate, 
            .(pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude)]
```

Comment: Using the data.table code, would I be able to read and compare for the either table? Should I use a for loop?

Comment: as in compare the `td1` table with the `td` table?

Comment: I want to compare a date(2016-01-01) to all dates in the second column of the table and store pickup latitude and longitude of the dates which are satisfy the condition.

Comment: that is exactly what both of these methods are doing

Comment: See edits - both `df1` and `td1` will equal your `Pickup` data.frame in your for loop

Comment: for(i in 1:nrow(td)){ 
td1 <- td[tpep_pickup_datetime == mydate, 
          .(Pickup_longitude, Pickup_latitude, Pickup)]

}
should this code be fine?

Comment: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Pickup_longitude' not found
seem to be getting this error

Comment: replace `Pickup_longitude` and `Pickup_latitude` with whatever their corresponding column names are in your original data frame

Comment: idx = 0
idx[1:(31*24)] = 1
idx[(31*24+1)] = nrow(TripData)+1

#idx[j] is the row index of the first data in hour j
for(j in 1:(31*24-1)){
  for(i in (idx[j]):nrow(TripData)){
    td1 <- td[tpep_pickup_datetime == mydate, 
              .(pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude)]
  }
  idx[j+1] = i
  mydate = mydate + 3600
}
this is the code i used. It ran successfully, but there is no data stored in td1.

Comment: You are over thinking, you don't need the foor loop. `data.table` automatically works through the entire data set. just run the code i posted as is

Comment: Tried that, it says "no data available for td1"

Comment: Do your date times in `dt` have times as well? It probably has no data because it is trying to match date times to mydate which most likely is set to "2016-01-01 00:00:00". You may have to use the `lubridate` package to extract the day out and then compare them

Comment: @NikhilSanjayPawar I updated both answers to account for this date error. Try to run it now. You will need to have the `lubridate` package installed

Comment: Tried the new code after installing lubridate. Sorry still seem to be getting "no data available for td1".

Comment: Can you post the results of `dput (TripData)` to your question?

Comment: 7.8, 26.76, 18.96, 8.16, 70.01, 6.36, 9.8, 15.3, 12.95, 21.3, 
    8.8, 5.3, 14.16, 9.8, 30.3, 15.8, 27.25, 7.3, 6.96, 5.8, 
    12, 4.8, 11.62, 6.3, 9.3, 29.3, 42.3, 8.3, 17.76, 8.8, 5.3, 
    8.3, 19.3, 13.56, 21.3, 8.3, 17.3, 8.16, 9.3, 21.8, 8.8, 
    7.3, 10.1, 10.56, 12.3, 10.3, 7.55, 8.3, 7.8, 9.8, 12.3, 
    6.3, 7.56, 7.3, 11.75, 3.8, 24.3, 12.36, 30.95, 9.8, 10.56, 
    8.8, 7.3, 18.8, 11.8, 11.15, 9.36, 7.56, 6.96, 12.3, 11.6, 
    10.9, 5.76, 31.56, 11.3, 15.8, 7.56, 3.8, 14.15, 5.3, 13.8, 
    22.56, 9.3, 9.3, 6.3, 9.1, 10.8, 13.39, 10.3, 20.16, 9.36,

Comment: Edit your question and put it in there not in this comment thread

Comment: Yes I did that, please guide further.

Comment: So i noticed in your dput outputs that your column names were `pickup_longitude` and `pickup_latitude` rather than `Pickup_longitude` and `Pickup_latitude`. This change will cause no data to be picked up as R is case sensitive. So that could be the cause of your problem. You should see my comment on your question about the dput output if you still need any further help

Comment: I updated the column names in my answer so hopefully it will work now

Comment: I had made those changes earlier as well, that doesnt seem to be the problem. As td1 was still showing "no data available".

Comment: you should add the output to `dput()` where you only include around ten lines, while ensuring that at least one instance of `date(tpep_pickup_datetime) == "2016-01-01"`. You can do this by doing `dput(TripData[x:y,])` where x = lower indices and y = upper indices. Other than that my only further suggestion without actually having the data is that you should ensure that you actually have occurrences of the specified date in your data.table

Comment: Is there a problem because the date format are diffrerent? the table has 2016/01/01 and I'm comparing it to 2016-01-01

Comment: Potentially. Try changing the format of `mydate` and see if it works

Comment: Doesnt work. I actually have to do another task now. I just have to store all dates together which are equal to "2016-01-01". Then compare their times. For times which are equal,I have to add another number to represent the simultaneous events. Could you please guide for the same.

Comment: `td1 <- td[, date := lubridate::date(tpep_pickup_datetime)][date == as.POSIXct("2016-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d"), count := .N, by = tpep_pickup_datetime]`

Comment: for future reference, when you have new questions, you should post them as a separate question